# Set transparency for named color directly (Context)

Tags: context, transparency

I know that I can define a new transparent color with RGB values, such as:

`\definecolor[transparentturquoise][r=.567,g=.800,b=.808,t=.5,a=1] %darkturquoise`

That's ok but it's somewhat inconvenient to look up the color scheme table and then set the color. Is there any way to simplify this a bit, that is, to state, e.g.:

`\definecolor[turquesa][darkturquoise][t=.5,a=1]`?

```
\setupcolors[state=start]
\usecolors[x11]

\setuppagenumbering[state=stop]


\setupindenting[yes,small]

\definecolor [transparentolivedrab3]  [r=.677,g=.604,b=.804,t=.5,a=1]

\definecolor[transparentturquoise][r=.567,g=.800,b=.808,t=.5,a=1] %darkturquoise

%\definecolor[turquesa][darkturquoise][t=.5,a=1]

\starttext


\startframedtext[background=color,backgroundcolor=transparentturquoise,color=blue,corner=round,width=.5\textwidth]
\setupindenting[yes,small]
\input knuth
\stopframedtext

\stoptext
```

Comment: This looks like a bug, but to be sure you should ask on the mailing list. In my personal opinion transparency has no place in PDF anyway.

Comment: `\definecolor[turquesa][\processcolorcomponents{darkturquoise},t=0.5,a=1]` (see https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Color) works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Henri suggests, this may be a bug. In the meantime, a workaround is `\processcolorcomponents` and overwrite transparency components `t` and `a`, if defined.

```
\usecolors[x11]
\setuppagenumbering[state=stop]
\setupindenting[yes,small]
\definecolor[turquesa][\processcolorcomponents{darkturquoise},t=.5,a=1]
\setupbodyfont[big]
\starttext
\startframedtext[background=color,backgroundcolor=darkturquoise,color=blue,corner=round,width=\textwidth]
\setupindenting[yes,small]
\input knuth
\stopframedtext
\startframedtext[background=color,backgroundcolor=turquesa,color=blue,corner=round,width=\textwidth]
\setupindenting[yes,small]
\input knuth
\stopframedtext
\stoptext
```

[image]